# padding for cells of one column not for all cells of table

Tags: tables, longtable

I want that just one of my columns cells have top padding.
I tried :

```
\def\arraystretch{factor}%
```

but the result is not ideal. because I don't want all columns have the top padding.

is there anyway to specify top padding for cells of just one column?

**Edit**

I have a long table with 10 rows and 4 columns that the 4th column has image.
this is my code (summarized with 3 columns ):

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{8cm}|p{2cm}|}
\caption{my caption}
\label{table:10.1}
\\
\hline

\centering titile 1     &  \centering title 2 & \centering title 3 &  {\centering  title 4}  \\
\hline \hline
first r first c &  first r second c &  first r third c & 
      \begin{minipage}{.12\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{table10-1-1.png}
    \end{minipage}
 \\
\hline
second r first c & second r second c  &  second r third c & 
\begin{minipage}{.12\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{table10-1-2.png}
    \end{minipage}
     \\
\hline
third r first c &  third r second d &  third r third c & 
\begin{minipage}{.12\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{table10-1-3.png}
    \end{minipage} 

    \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
```

The result is like this:

[image]

I tried to get padding with {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{4}% but the result in not good:
[image]

It would be fine if just cells of 4th column had padding.

anyway I have another problem in this table:

1- Text in the cells are justified and sometimes the space between the words are too much.

I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: Try using `m` column specifier instead of `p`.

Comment: Follow the instructions in [Column and row padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764): Use struts or move the content up/down using `\raisebox`. Could you provide a more comprehensive example though, since the question is very general at the moment...

Comment: @karlkoeller it doesn't work

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @karlkoeller Post is edited. already thankful.

Comment: @Werner Post is edited. I read that post for several times but couldn't have any ideal result.

Comment: `\label{variability_impl_mech}` produces the two extra lines. You already have a label after `caption`. Do you need both labels?

Comment: @Ignasi Oh! thank you. I changed my code several times and I forgot to remove that.

Comment: I edited the post again. There was a stupid mistake. thanks to @Ignasi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use `minipage` for the images, you can add some padding there:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}% just for not having overfull lines
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable,array}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{8cm}|p{2cm}|}
\caption{my caption}
\label{table:10.1}
\\
\hline

\centering title 1 &
  \centering title 2 &
  \centering title 3 &
  \centering\arraybackslash title 4 \\
\hline \hline
first r first c &  first r second c &  first r third c & 
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \vspace{12pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}\par
  \vspace{12pt}
  \end{minipage}
 \\
\hline
second r first c & second r second c  &  second r third c & 
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \vspace{12pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}\par
  \vspace{12pt}
  \end{minipage}
\\
\hline
third r first c &  third r second d &  third r third c & 
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \vspace{12pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}\par
  \vspace{3pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}\par
  \vspace{12pt}
  \end{minipage}
\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Note that I stated the width of the `minipage` as wide as the `p` column it's in, and the same for the pictures.

The input might be simplified, taking into account that the scheme is fixed.

[image]

With small changes you can have the text in the first three columns beginning at the top. Here I used `\vspace{0pt}` at the top of the minipages

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}% just for not having overfull lines
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable,array}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{8cm}|p{2cm}|}
\caption{my caption}
\label{table:10.1}
\\
\hline

\centering title 1 &
  \centering title 2 &
  \centering title 3 &
  \centering\arraybackslash title 4 \\
\hline \hline
first r first c &  first r second c &  first r third c & 
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}\par
  \vspace{12pt}
  \end{minipage}
 \\
\hline
second r first c & second r second c  &  second r third c & 
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}\par
  \vspace{12pt}
  \end{minipage}
\\
\hline
third r first c &  third r second d &  third r third c & 
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}\par
  \vspace{3pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}\par
  \vspace{12pt}
  \end{minipage}
\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. Is there any way that texts of cells begin from top of the cell?

Comment: @AshKan Yes, use `\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}`; you'll probably want to reduce the amount in the first `\space`.